# Passing form data to controller method - child properties are not getting filled in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, javascriptmvc

My app is using JavascriptMVC on the client side, and ASP MVC is basically functioning only as a REST service.  Here's a typical controller method:

```
public JsonResult Update(CustomerDto dto)
{
  var repository = Factory.NewCustomerRepository())
  // ... Convert DTO back to entity and save changes
  return Json(dto);
}
```

The problem is, my CustomerDTO contains some properties that aren't getting converted from the form data into the objects that they should be.  For example, PhoneNumbers:

```
public class CustomerDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumberDto[] PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    // ... more properties
}
public class PhoneNumberDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller action, PhoneNumbers will have the correct number of elements in the array, but each object will have only null/default values.  I've verified that the request is sending all of the appropriate form data:

```
Id          26
FirstName   A
LastName    Person
MiddleName  Test
PhoneNumbers[0][CustomerID  26
PhoneNumbers[0][Id] 5
PhoneNumbers[0][Label]  Mobile
PhoneNumbers[0][Number] (555)555-5555
PhoneNumbers[1][CustomerID  26
PhoneNumbers[1][Id] 8
PhoneNumbers[1][Label]  Home
PhoneNumbers[1][Number] (654)654-6546
```

Any ideas on what could be going on?  Am I just wrong in thinking that MVC3 can map nested objects from the form values automatically?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the request should look like this if you want the default model binder to successfully bind those values (notice `PhoneNumbers[0].CustomerID` instead of `PhoneNumbers[0][CustomerID]`):

```
Id                          26
FirstName                   A
LastName                    Person
MiddleName                  Test
PhoneNumbers[0].CustomerID  26
PhoneNumbers[0].Id          5
PhoneNumbers[0].Label       Mobile
PhoneNumbers[0].Number      (555)555-5555
PhoneNumbers[1].CustomerID  26
PhoneNumbers[1].Id          8
PhoneNumbers[1].Label       Home
PhoneNumbers[1].Number      (654)654-6546
```

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) for the wire format used for collections.

As an alternative you could use [JSON requests](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx).

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back to this question - I had to switch to a different project for a couple of weeks.  

@Darin - That makes sense - my problem though is that I don't have any control over the format itself - it is being serialized by jquery, and this is what its sending.  I'm using JavascriptMVC, which includes a .save() helper method on the model objects, which invokes jquery behind the scenes.

I have stepped through the JMVC code, and I don't see anything non-standard - it looks to me like jquery is handling the formatting itself.  Any ideas?

Comment: @jdraper3, no need to apologize. It was you who asked the question. Personally I know the answer so I am not in a hurry :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help - I ended up using JSON requests instead and that works great.